# Can't change the frames of .xib UI objects in code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, initialization, frame, xib

I am trying to re-write my code to allow me to use xibs to design custom UIViews for re-use throughout my projects. I have created a class called SlidesView which has a .xib of the same name. I have set it up using the following IBOutlets:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ivMain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lHeader;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *tvMain;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ivIcon;
```

I have made sure these are all properly connected within the .xib file. I also have a function which I want to use to setup all the initial data for the view:

```
- (void)setupUsingCenter:(CGPoint)center mainImage:(UIImage *)mainImage mainText:(NSString *)mainText header:(NSString *)header andIconImage:(UIImage *)iconImage
```

The 'setupUsingCenter:self ...' body looks as follows:

```
// First check for a main image and image icon    
    if (mainImage != nil)
    {
        // Set the image
        [self.ivMain setImage:mainImage];
        [self.ivMain setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 10, 10)];

        // If image icon set that too
        if (iconImage != nil)
        {
            [self.ivIcon setImage:iconImage];
        }
    }
```

And finally I load this .xib using the following code:

```
NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SlidesView" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[SlidesView class]])
            {
                SlidesView *slidesView = (SlidesView *)view;
                [slidesView setupUsingCenter:self.vPlaceholder.center mainImage:slideImage mainText:slideText header:slideTitle andIconImage:slideIcon];
                [slidesView setTextColours:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]];
                [self.view addSubview:slidesView];
                self.viewPopup = slidesView;
            }
        }
```

I have put in the random setFrame parameters for testing purposes but for some reason the frame doesn't change. However, the image on the ivMain does change. Can anyone explain how I can change the frame for my UI objects? Also, why does it allow me to change the image but the frame seems un-editable, doesn't this mean it must be initialised?

Any help is much appreciated, 
Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Are you sure `autolayout` is disabled on the `.xib` ? It is my understanding that you cannot edit frames when `autolayout` is on.

If that's the case, you can either disable `autolayout` for that particular `.xib`, or you can work on `constraints` instead of the `frame` property

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, was driving me crazy why this wasn't working!

Comment: I have an UIButton in my XIB and I can't change its image even autolayout is disabled

Answer (score 4):

The use of autosizing may cause some unexpected behaviors also the autoresize subviews.

You can try something like this:

```
[View setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];
```

And:

```
[View setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];
```

Where **View** is the UIView that you want to apply that behavior.